# Is the Australian 3 Month BBSW rate annualised?

Tags: libor, rates, interbank-rates

I am looking at the 3 month BBSW reference rate and not sure if this is annualised. I understand for example, some of the LIBOR rates are annualised.

Comment: Money market rates are always annualized.